# Exibir dias negativos em cálculo entre datas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma listagem de contas a receber.

Para ficar interativo, estou criando um IF para mostrar quando está próximo.

### Problema

Não mostra data negativas, que representaria fatura vencida.

Nesse caso da imagem baixo, hoje são `08/02/2020`, **a tag que deveria ser mostrada, é a de** `Vencido`.

[image: mostrando resultado errado]

### Código

```
if (data[5] == null) {
  hoje = new Date('<?= date('Y - m - d '); ?>');
  data = new Date(data[4]);
  diferenfa = Math.abs(data.getTime() - hoje.getTime());
  nDias = Math.ceil(diferenfa / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  if (nDias >= 8) {
    return '<span class="label">Faltam ' + nDias + ' dias</span>';

  } else if (nDias <= 7 && nDias >= 3) {
    return '<span class="label label-warning">Está proximo</span>';

  } else if (nDias <= 2 && nDias >= 1) {
    return '<span class="label label-sm label-yellow">Amanhã</span>';

  } else if (nDias == 0) {
    return '<span class="label label-info">Hoje</span>';

  }else if (nDias < 0){
    return '<span class="label label-info">Vencido</span>';
  }



} else {
  return '<span class="label label-success">Pago</span>';
}
```

### Pergunta

Como posso montar esses `if`s de forma que funcione corretamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O maior problema parece ser a fórmula adotada. Eu não usei a função `abs()` que tira o sinal. Se estiver vencido o resultado dá negativo, com essa função qualquer número negativo vira positivo, então não cai no `if` correto.

Eu mudei algumas coisas para facilitar o teste, mas outras foi só simplificação do código.

```js
var hoje = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
var data = new Date(new Date(2020, 1, 7).toDateString());
var nDias = Math.ceil((data - hoje) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
if (nDias > 7) console.log('<span class="label">Faltam ' + nDias + ' dias</span>');
else if (nDias > 2) console.log('<span class="label label-warning">Está proximo</span>');
else if (nDias > 0) console.log('<span class="label label-sm label-yellow">Amanhã</span>');
else if (nDias == 0) console.log('<span class="label label-info">Hoje</span>');
else console.log('<span class="label label-info">Vencido</span>');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/DateDifference.js).